# Историческая блокировка принятых решений

Tags: поддержка

> У вас как-то две проблемы в одном вопросе смешались: "ставить на решения сообщества историческую блокировку" и "вопросы с исторической блокировкой исчезают из результатов поиска". Давайте как-то отделим мух от котлет?

**Нет у меня двух проблем. Решение ставить блокировку уже принято Николасом. В этом вопросе я утверждаю, что историческая блокировка на эту роль не годится.**

---

[Предлагается](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6836/178988) ставить на решения сообщества историческую блокировку. Это нужно для того, чтобы после принятия решения голосование по вопросу прекратилось, и несогласные, которых будут посылать в вопрос не голосовали против.

Проблема заключается в том, что вопросы с исторической блокировкой **исчезают из списка вопросов по метке**:

[image: скриншот поиска по метке]

Поиск с указанием дополнительных параметров (например `is:q`) работает:

[image: скриншот поиска]

Считаю, что вопросы должны быть доступны в сводке по метке. В связи с этим, может есть более подходящий тип блокировки, который не будет скрывать вопросы?

Comment: [Если верить MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for), то вопросы пропадают только из списка вопросов, но их можно найти поиском. Более того, это происходит только на основном сайте, не Мете!

Comment: Заблокировал ваш вопрос для эксперимента. Посмотрим, сможете ли вы его найти в списке и/или через поиск.

Comment: Снял блокировку. В итоге у меня: вопрос я ваш вижу в списках вопросов, кроме главной страницы, в поиске его найти так же можно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, во-первых, результаты поиска как-то кэшируются - я несколько раз сталкивался с тем, что добавленные к вопросам метки не сразу там появляются, а во-вторых, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Я подождал чуть–чуть! :) Вопрос с поиском, конечно, интересный. Постараюсь выяснить.

Comment: У вас как-то две проблемы в одном вопросе смешались: *"ставить на решения сообщества историческую блокировку"* и *"вопросы с исторической блокировкой исчезают из результатов поиска"*. Давайте как-то отделим мух от котлет? А то получается "не могу найти дома ключи, давайте перестанем строить дома?"

Comment: @Kromster, вообще не понимаю, как твой комментарий связан с моим вопросом. Перечитай его ещё раз.

Comment: @Qwertiy дело в расстановке акцентов. Щас отредактирую.

Comment: @Kromster, акцент был на том, что надо вместо исторической блокировки использовать какую-то другую, но именно эту фразу ты почему-то удалил...

Comment: @Qwertiy если акцент на том, что вскольз упомянуто в другом ответе - логичнее там оставить комментарий и сослаться на этот вопрос. */емнип, мы с вами не переходили на "ты"/*

Comment: @Kromster, акцент на том, что блокировка нужна другая. А историческая упомянута в куче мест, не только по ссылке. По поводу "ты" - я так со всеми общаюсь, да и вообще вроде у программистов так принято. Не стоит обращать внимания, это ничего не значит.

Comment: @Qwertiy а разве проблема в том что исторический вопрос не ищется? Я только что ввел "бэтмен" и получил вопрос. То есть получается ваш вопрос к историческим блокировкам вообще не относится.

Comment: @Kromster, впервые вижу сочетание "сводка по метке". Может всё-таки "список вопросов по метке", если уж так не хочется использовать "поиск"? Хотя на мой взгляд, это всё-таки поиск.

Answer (score 2):

У вас как-то две проблемы в одном вопросе смешались: "ставить на решения сообщества историческую блокировку" и "вопросы с исторической блокировкой исчезают из результатов поиска". Давайте как-то отделим мух от котлет?

1. Вопросы с исторической блокировкой отлично ищутся - вводим в поиск "бэтмен" и видим искомый вопрос на 1 месте.
2. Метка [1 апреля] не показывает ни один исторически заблокированный вопрос. (создал новый вопрос - он показывается).

Похоже что вопросы с исторической блокировкой действительно скрываются из сводки по метке.

Comment: _"вводим в поиск "бэтмен""_ - ага, а весь свод решений не ищется, потому что только по метке поиск. _"Заблокирована метка"_ - метку нельзя заблокировать.

Comment: Уточните, что такое "весь свод решений" ?

Comment: Вот хочу я все актуальные решения посмотреть и делаю поиск по метке. А результат-то пустой.

Comment: Что такое "все актуальные решения" ? Метка заблокирована. Если вам надо разблокировать метку - поднимите такую тему на Мете.

Comment: Что значит "метка заблокирована"? Нет такого понятия.

Comment: Хм, действительно, метку можно использовать. Создал вопрос с ней -
 он ищется и показывается в сводке по метке. То есть бага в том, что по метке нельзя найти исторически заблокированные вопросы?

Comment: Ну если считать это багом, то да. Но, насколько я понимаю, это не баг, а фича?

Comment: @Qwertiy пожалуй, вы правы